# How to search string in concat string in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my query

```
$this->db->select('
CONCAT(customers.first_name, " ", customers.last_name) AS full_name
');
$this->db->where('full_name', $customerSearch);
$run_q = $this->db->get('customers');
```

But I receive errors.

```
Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'
```

What's wrong with me?

Comment: [From the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data): "*`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$this->db->select('
CONCAT(customers.first_name, " ", customers.last_name) AS full_name
');
$this->db->where(CONCAT(customers.first_name, " ", customers.last_name), $customerSearch);
$run_q = $this->db->get('customers');
```

You are getting error because you can't use alias of 'derived column'(i.e. full_name) in 'where' clause.